# Django: using Images in Hyperlinks

Tags: html, django, image

im pretty new to Django (as in no Knowledge so far) and a project requires me to include a Image inside of a hyperlink.
just including the  inside of the hyperlinks created the error message

```
'blocktrans' doesn't allow other block tags (seen "static 'pretix_app/Instagram.png'") inside it
```

my code so far is

```
li ><img src="{% static 'pretix_app/YouTube.png' %}" alt="Youtube_icon" style="alignment: left;vertical-align:middle; width: 20px; padding-right: 5px"    >
             {% with 'target="blank" href="https://www.youtube.com"'|safe as a_attr %}
                {% blocktrans trimmed %}   <a {{ a_attr }}>    Social Media-target   {% endblocktrans %}
                {% endwith %}</li>
```

This produces a working hyperlink, but does not include the image (which is required as a social media hyperlink)
The "safe as  attr"-method was copied from a working template included in the source code.

Does anybody know if it is possible to include Images in Hyperlinks, and if yes, how?

Thanks in advance for any help

Comment: There is another `blocktrans` template tag within which the code you mentioned in your question is included. This is causing issues as there must be no other tags inside the `blocktrans` template tag. Please show that part of your template.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hello Corinari and welcome to StackOverflow.

As the Django log says, the `blocktrans` (should be `blocktranslate` since Django 3.1 [ref](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/i18n/translation/#translate-template-tag)) may not contain other tags, which in this case is the `{% static 'pretix_app/YouTube.png' %}` part. We need to remove that part.

One possible way is to use the `as` statement. You could have the `static` tag outside your `blocktrans` block and pass through a variable, like this:

```html
{% static 'pretix_app/YouTube.png' as yt_icon %}
{% blocktrans %}
    <li>
        <img src="{{ yt_icon }}" alt="Youtube_icon" style="alignment: left;vertical-align:middle; width: 20px; padding-right: 5px"/>
        ...
    </li>
{% endblocktrans %}
```

This will fix your current error. There are, however several further notes I have. First is the probable typo `pretix_app` in the static path. The other, much more important, as Abdul says in his comment, you will reach another error with the second `blocktrans` block. As far as I know from what you have posted here you should not need the second `blocktrans` nested within the first one. You will be able to translate the whole thing as one.

Comment: Thanks for your help, i was able to fix it.

Comment: @Corinari Glad to help